# GMM model with R

Tags: r, econometrics, finance, generalized-moments

I am trying to run a GMM model, based on the Fama-Macbeth technique for robust s.e. (use this method for correction in auto-correlation and conditional heteroskedasticity). I am using R, after I have run the classic two step method, and specifically i use [this paper for details](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmm/vignettes/gmm_with_R.pdf). I only care about a one step GMM, but i can not understand how can i obtain the new model as an output that it looks like the output of the linear regression with the appropriate tests. For instance, when you run a linear model you can do

```
model1<-lm(R_FF_25_port ~ exmkt_return+smb+hml) 
summary(model1)
```

and you take the outpout of the FF3 model. In case someone wants to obtain the model with GMM, he needs to use

```
f1 <- EMR
f2 <- SMB
f3 <- HML
h <- cbind(f1, f2, f3)
res2 <- gmm(pvw1 ~ f1 + f2 + f3, x = h)
coef(res2)
summary(res2)
```

but you do not obtain the results as in the case of the linear model, where the output gives you the  results with the new t-stats, to make the comparison. In any case I am very confused, and if I want to run a one step GMM, i think that in the command of `res2` i need to write in the end, this, `wmatrix="ident"`. I also try to run a model with lags in the variables, but i do not succeed to make it work. If anyone else tried to make such an implementation, I could be glad for guidance. Thank you in advance!

See the following paradigm [from Wayne Chang](https://sites.google.com/site/waynelinchang/r-code)

```
library(gmm)
data(Finance)
df.fin <- data.frame(rm=Finance[1:500,"rm"], rf=Finance[1:500,"rf"])
# gmm package author Pierre Chaussé recommends using formula approach for linear problems
summary(gmm(rm ~ rf, ~rf, data=df.fin))

# standard approach
g <- function(theta, x)
{ m.1 <- x[,"rm"] - theta[1] - theta[2]*x[,"rf"] 
m.z <- (x[,"rm"] - theta[1] - theta[2]*x[,"rf"])*x[,"rf"]
f <- cbind(m.1, m.z)
 return(f)}
summary(gmm(g, df.fin, t0=c(0,0), method = "BFGS", control=list(fnscale=1e-8)))
summary(gmm(g, df.fin, t0=c(0,0), method = "BFGS", control=list(fnscale=1e-8), kernel="Bartlett", bw=bwNeweyWest)) # use Newey-West '94 standard errors
```

I can not understand whether this gmm command runs a single factor model and what this model is. I am trying to adjust this code to run a multifactor model, i.e. $R=a+b_1F_1+b_2F_2+b_3F_3$, does anybody know how can i adjust this example to a multifactor one?

Comment: Could I use somehow this paradigm? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/338663/generalized-method-of-moments-estimation-in-r-with-plm-and-gmm

Comment: Could you paste your comments into the main post? Please use appropriate formatting for code (there is a button above the editor window for that).

Comment: Is it better in this way?

Comment: Better, thank you! (I do not have an answer, sorry.)

Comment: Ok, i undestand, but tell me something I do not understand, what does this mean gmm(rm ~ rf, ~rf, data=df.fin)? When we use the linear model or the panel model, and write x~y, then it means $x=a+by$...in this case, i think it is something else, becasue it also uses ~rf in the second argument

Comment: I don't know what that means. If I were you, I would open the help file for the function to find out.

Comment: I have done this so many times...it confuses me more than it makes me understand it, but I will give it a shot again...and again....